# ANTLR semantic predicates in lexer rules

Tags: antlr

I have comment rules in lexer as follows

STARSLASH : '/*' ;

MULTILINECOMMENT : STARSLASH (options {greedy=false;} : .) '*/' ;

SINGLELINECOMMENT : '//' ~('\n')* ;

Now I have to write another lexer rule that starts with '/' and ends with '/'. When I write this rule as follows, I'm getting an error.

SLASH_RULE : '/' (options {greedy=false;} : .)* '/' ;

I'm using ANTLR3.2. How can I write this rule SLASH_RULE?

Comment: MULTILINECOMMENT : '/*' (options {greedy=false;} : .) '*/' ;

Comment: While posting the question, I've given as '/*' but when I submit, it got changed to '/'

Comment: Almost every Token satisfying MULTILINECOMMENT would satisfy SLASH_RULE. Is that intended? Are you certain that this rule is placed correctly in the lexer, perhaps you should provide some context (the meaning of slash_rule and the error message).

Comment: I would like to match the pattern that starts with '/*' to MULTILINECOMMENT;  pattern that starts with '//' to SINGLELINECOMMENT; pattern that starts with '/' followed by anything except * and /  to SLASH_RULE. Is that possible?. I'm not sure about the order in which these lexer rules have to be written. Right now, I'm following the same order in which I've mentioned in the code snippet

Comment: Your grammar is not `'/' followed by anything except * and /` have you tried to insert `~'*'` (not asterisk) after the slash of slash rule.